# How to hide Builder item in October CMS backend menu?

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-widgets

I'm beginner with october CMS. How am I able to hide Builder item from top menu in backend for specific user? When I disable all permissions of new administrator until the Builder one - create and edit plugins, I see not only my plugins, but Builder itself, too.

Sorry for my English

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just do not give them permissions of the builder, so `do NOT` make them `super user`. and `deny permission` of `the builder` to `hide menu item` and `access to builder`.

[image]

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. 

I just worried, that if i disable this feature, it will completely hide modules from builder, too.